# In what way, if any, can the axioms of set theory be themselves well-ordered?

Tags: set-theory, axiom

In ["Independence and Large Cardinals"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/independence-large-cardinals/#IntHie), Peter Koellner writes:

> ... it turns out that when one restricts [attention] to those theories that "arise in nature" the interpretability ordering is quite simple: There are no descending chains and no incomparable elements... for theories that "arise in nature", we have a well-ordered hierarchy...

In ["Large Cardinals and Determinacy"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/large-cardinals-determinacy/#NatAxi) he talks about degrees in an order of evidence and says:

> Ultimately one would like to find axioms that are *minimal* in the evidentness order.

Elsewhere, consider Paul Cohen's claim that the powerset axiom is a "bold new axiom," a "totally new and more powerful principle" compared to the axiom of replacement by itself:

> Thus ***C*** is greater than ℵ<sub>*n*</sub>, ℵ<sub>ω</sub>,... etc.

Let ℵ<sub>ψ</sub> stand for a cardinal given by an axiom, where ψ is some axiom. Then Cohen's claim is that for all κ, λ, if κ is an element only of ℵ<sub>Replacement</sub> but λ is an element of ℵ<sub>℘(κ)</sub>, then κ < λ. This appears to order infinite powersets over "mere" replacement sets, so to speak.

While working on a derivation of CH in my own axiomatic set theory, then, I had to ask myself the question whether (and if so, in what sense) the axioms of the theory are themselves well-ordered?† I can see this question as taking three forms:

1. Are the axioms *simpliciter* well-ordered? **Quick answer: no, they are logically "simultaneous."**
2. Is our *justification for believing* a set of axioms well-orderable?
3. Is our *application* of a set of axioms well-orderable?

Now suppose our justification process is well-orderable. In terms of this supposition, I actually codified the "minimal element in the ordering" as itself this principle: "Our acceptance of a set of axioms is justifiable as far as it is well-orderable." This doesn't require us to have actually fully self-consciously done such a thing as assign an order to our belief in our axioms, let me note. As long as we might as well have subconsciously done so, then we are actually justified in accepting the axioms that we accept.

Or so it seems to me (I wish I could remember how I originally wrote down the above ideas as it seemed more plausible then). Waiving all that, let's go back to [Zermelo's objection to Cantor's sense of temporal well-ordering as the intuitive proof of the well-ordering principle in general](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zermelo-set-theory/#ImpProBefZer):

> Here, the intuition of time is being applied to a process that goes beyond all intuition...

But the application of the axioms occurs in time regardless, so is it possible to apply an alleged fact of temporal well-ordering to the application of the axioms to go on to say that there should, in fact, be a "preferred" sequence of applications (starting from the axiom of the empty set, say)?

†<sub>(The idea is in part to derive, "℘(κ) is definite," from the collation of union, powerset, and replacement under a single principle, *transcension*, that says, "There is an infinite sequence of hyperoperations on the aleph numbers," with powerset *defined* by its place in the sequence, as the equivalent of an exponential function. There's more to it but this isn't the place to go over all that; I just want to illustrate where I'm trying to go...)</sub>

Comment: Surely there are only countably many axioms in any axiomatic system consisting of finite-length strings over an at most countably infinite language. You can well-order the axioms lexicographically, or by inducing a well-order from any bijection with the natural numbers. I would not think this is controversial in the least. it seems obvious.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What does it mean for a **justification process** to be well-orderable?

Comment: @user4894 To be fair I think the OP may be asking something more subtle (because of lines like "Is our justification for believing a set of axioms well-orderable?") but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: It would mean there was a first axiom whose acceptance was justified, followed by a second, etc. Then rather than believe the axioms "haphazardly," we would come to believe them in a definite sequence. Or so the goal would be...

Comment: The question is very hard to parse. Is there supposed to be any relation between it and interpretability ordering of theories beyond both being orderings? If not, I suggest removing that part. You say the question of ordering axioms came up in your work, so wouldn't the *relevant* ordering critically depend on what it is to be used for there, which you do not tell us about? Or is this also a side issue? And if what Koellner says is the template then shouldn't we look at mere *ordering* first, independently motivated, and *then* see if it happens to be a well ordering, instead of baking it in?

Comment: I got the impression that Koellner was saying that large cardinal axioms are well-ordered under the interpretability relation (he says we start from the theory ZFC-Infinity and continue upward, and he refers to theories as recursively enumerable axiom systems)? The relevance to my own work I glossed in the footnote (but I'm not trying to vet a pet theory here so I don't think I should go into more detail on that score).

Comment: Or I will at least say that the gist of the argument (in my own work) is supposed to be that the axiom of replacement is not justified "until" the powerset operation is defined. I have a memory of seeing it said somewhere that the definite powerset operation does fix on ℵ1 for the Continuum but I don't know if my memory is reliable here...

Comment: What people mean by the large cardinal axioms being ordered by interpretability or consistency strength is that *theories* ZFC+A are so ordered. You can certainly choose just a fragment of ZFC and compare theories obtained by adding axioms to it one at a time, but it will be an ordering *relative to that fragment*. I do not think you can get an absolute ordering of ZFC axioms as such this way. There is ordering by presupposition, which may be closer to your idea, when you need an axiom to define an object used to formulate another axiom, e.g. Infinity presupposes Empty Set, and Choice Union.

Answer (score 0):

> Are the axioms simpliciter well-ordered?

Any finite or countable set can trivially be assigned a well-ordering.  Simply list the elements of the set one by one, on integer-numbered lines, and the well-order is given by the number of each line.

The axioms of ZFC are countable and so can trivially be assigned a well-ordering.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory lists the axioms in order 1-9.  Axioms 3 and 6 are actually axiom schemas, which means they are countably infinite.  We can simply list the other 7 axioms, and then alternate between listing elements of axiom schema 3 and axiom schema 6.

> Is our justification for believing a set of axioms well-orderable?

A well-ordering is a structure assigned to a set.  Is "our justification for believing" a set?  Unless you can give some way in which "our justification for believing" is a set, you cannot assign a well-ordering to it.

> Is our application of a set of axioms well-orderable?

Again, in what way is "our application of a set of axioms" a set?

We might interpret this as asking whether the set of *proofs* derived from the ZFC axioms are well-orderable.  The answer is yes, because the set of proofs is countable, and all countable sets are trivially well-orderable.  (Just write them down one by one, and the order in which you write them is their well-order.)  For instance, proofs can be well-ordered by:

- P1 <= P2 if P1 written out contains no more symbols than P2
- If P1 and P2 contain the same number of symbols, then P1 <= P2 if P1 appears no later in the lexicographic ordering of proofs of that length than P2.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The axioms are countably infinite so can be well-ordered despite this minor expositional error in calling them finite.

Comment: @user4894 (1) That's why I was careful to say "this doesn't contradict your broader point. (2) It's a minor expositional error in this context, but [it often causes problems later on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle#In_ZFC) so I think it's still worth pointing out.

Comment: So we're clear, the axiom system I'm using is not countably infinite, but uncountably so. One of the ideas is that there should in principle be as many large cardinal axioms as there are transfinite numbers. So there is a ω1th axiom of infinity under the scheme, and so on (this is in keeping with something Maddy says about some set theorists thinking that for any LC axiom, there should always be a larger one to be found).

Comment: Then there is not just the LC hierarchy but the LC puzzle, which is "finding out which indexed axiom each LC falls under," e.g let ℵψ0 = ℵ0 and ℵψ1 = the smallest uncountable inaccessible; then for example (assuming various other things) we ask: for ℵψ*n*, which *n* does the first measurable cardinal occur at? If that makes any sense... (I assume that most known LC axioms coincide with some ℵψ*n*.)

Comment: @KristianBerry So, what *language* are you using to formulate these axioms? There are only countably many sentences at all in the standard language of set theory, or indeed in any other countable language. And what does "ℵψn" mean exactly? I really don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah yes thanks for the correction

Comment: @causative I've deleted my original comment (and will delete this one shortly); thanks, and sorry for the nitpick!

Comment: The "ℵψ*n*" notation is an attempt to represent what Cohen was saying about the axioms of powerset and replacement. It would read, roughly, as "the aleph given by axiom of infinity *n*," so that the zeroth axiom of infinity gives us ℵ0, the next axiom gives us the smallest uncountable inaccessible, etc. ... I haven't gotten very far with explaining the language/logic behind the system (even to myself), I'm experimenting with some sort of erotetics instead of normal sentential logic.

Comment: For example, use the evocation relation in erotetic logic to express the powerset function like so: every set of answers to a set of questions evokes more questions than in the set of questions answered by the evocative set.

Comment: If you want to consider the idea of an uncountable number of distinct axioms, wouldn't you need some sort of [infinitary language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/#1) involving propositions with an (ordered) uncountable number of symbols?

Comment: @Hypnosifl that's what I suspect, but I need to learn a lot more before I commit to such a proposal in a specific way. I'm gunning for something like ℒ(ORD, ORD) it seems, but I need to be careful about how I say that...

Comment: I'll throw some more on this into chat, if it's worth anyone's time 