# Rawls' phrase "well-ordered society"

Tags: terminology, rawls

Given Rawls' near-constant recourse to mathematical examples and analogies in AToJ, what are the chances that his talk of well-ordered societies is to be understood in part in terms of well-ordered mathematical structures? Is this why he uses "from the perspective of the least advantaged member of society" as such a fundamental perspective from which to evaluate things, as the equivalent of a "minimal element in the ordering"?

(I ask this question because [elsewhere](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81063/in-what-way-if-any-can-the-axioms-of-set-theory-be-themselves-well-ordered) I posed the question of "well-ordered justification processes" but couldn't remember where I'd seen anything congruent with those described. Shame on me, after all, given the fact that AToJ is my favorite nonfiction book!)

Comment: Pls bear in mind the problematic nature of forcing of □P(math) to the □P(society) in general only via analogies or metaphors. It necessary that 9>7, however, it's not necessary our solar system having 9 planets instead of 7 planets... Semantic substitution in modal logic via subjective imaginary analogy is very limited without any further careful constraints...

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with philosophy of math, per the tag. It seems a trivial application of some math to philosophy and/or social science.

Comment: I tried to use just the tag "mathematics" and didn't notice that it switched out...

Comment: Your question got me thinking about symmetry, and uniqueness in relation to the properties of bosons & fermions. It feels like there is a natural parallel there, with using 'the original position'. The closest thing I found was a paper 'Uniqueness and symmetry in bargaining theories of justice' by J Thrasher. It doesn't approach things quantitively though.